# How to create a multi-tenant application in ReactJS with Azure Active Directory and MSAL?

Tags: authentication, multi-tenant, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform, msal-react

I'm building a Microsoft Identity Provider based multi-tenant app in React, and I'm wondering the best way to create and access per-tenant information or variables. For authentication I want to use Azure Active Directory and MSAL.

The application needs to have 2 functionalities.

1. Sign-up of the Tenant by its User with Global Admin access in order to provide authorization permissions.
2. Sign-in by any User of the corresponding Tenant.

A detailed step by step explanation and code will be appreciated.